# I am working on python in jupyter notebook. I have wrote the for loop code. I am getting some error

Tags: python, jupyter

Currently I am working on python in jupyter notebook. In that notebook I have wrote the **for loop** code like this:

```
values[23,52,59,37,48]
sum=0
length=1

for value in values:
    sum += value
    length += 1

print("Total sum:" + str(sum) + "-Average" + str(sum/))
```

I am getting the error like :

```
 File "<ipython-input-12-6d512127ab75>", line 9
   print("Total sum:" + str(sum) + "-Average" + str(sum/))
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone tell me how to correct it ?

Comment: Remove slash after the last "sum"

Comment: ya get it. the code is working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, the slash after the last sum produces the error.

Here is a litte prettier code for this problem. If you are not required to program from scratch (e.g. for learning purpose), I recommend to use Pythons built-in functions.

And for console output with variable values, string interpolation is a good choice.

```
values = [23,52,59,37,48]
_sum = sum(values)
_avg = _sum / len(values)
print(f"Total sum: {_sum}\nAverage: {_avg}")
```